# Android - copy and paste un-slelectable text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent

I am building an app which requires the user to copy and paste a ten digit identification number from another app on the phone. Only thing is, in the other app, the ID number is presented as a header/title bar. I am sure it is not an image with text. Most apps for custom text capture require the user to take a screenshot and use some OCR operation to harvest the text from an image.

I find this as taking too many steps for my users, some of whom may not even know how to take a screenshot with android using the volume and power buttons.

Is there any way to copy and paste text that is un-highlightable on an app without using a screenshot?
Can I code my app to add context menu option on long press any text on screen so I can grab this text?